# How can I have only one way to access my website, through the login screen with PHP?

Tags: php, html, redirect, authentication, web

I made a one user login for my website using PHP. After the user enters everything right, he is redirected to the main page with the following code:

```
if($username=='name'&& $password=='code'){
header('Location: photos.html');}
```

But if I enter the url of the website somedomain.com/photos.html, I am directed straight to the content without a login required. Instead of redirecting the user, is there a way I could have it all be on one page, so that the user has to log in?

Comment: a simple a approach to a single log in; which does not not requiring you to change your code is to use Apaches authentication: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/auth.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use PHP Session for that. For example in your doLogin page you can just add the following line in your code to add a Session :

```
$_SESSION['username'] = 'myUsername';
```

And after that in the page you can add the following line to check for every Session in your web :

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){

            header("Location:./index.php?msg=You must login first");
        }
        else{//do something}
```

Something like that. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

To clarify what the current response has said:

`$_SESSION['username']` is an array member of the "form variable," the way HTTP POST data is sent to and from PHP scripts. [You can learn more about external variables from the PHP.net documentation.](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php)

Using an HTML form, [which you can learn more about from this TutorialsPoint article on HTML forms](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_forms.htm), you can send the data from the input fields "into" a PHP script, in the way of "form variables" (via the `action=""` attribute of the HTML `<form></form>` tag), and use this to check if the data sent in is 'correct' for login purposes.

An example of this HTML form:

```
<!-- index.html -->

<!-- Other HTML code above this -->
<form action="login.php" method="POST">
    <h2>Username:</h2><br>
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" required autofocus>

    <h2>Password:</h2><br>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="username" required autofocus>

    <button name="submit" type="submit" value="login">Login</button>
</form>
```

Note that the `name=""` attribute of the `<input>` tags is what you will refer to in your PHP 'login' script.

*While I am not advocating storing your password in a PHP variable, I will do so in my example purely for simplicity. Furthermore, my example does not account for the possible future use of a database or any protection against any possible attacks.*

```
<?php
    session_start();

    // This is the script that will manage the login.
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $adminusername = 'foo';
        $adminpassword = 'bar';

        // the text in the quotes must what you wrote in the name=""
        // in the desired data's <input> tag
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        if (empty($username) || empty($password))
        {
            echo 'Missing credentials.';
        }
        else
        {
            if ($username == $adminusername && $password == $adminpassword)
            {
                $_SESSION['userId'] == $username;

                // redirects to photos.html if valid login
                header('Location: photos.html') 
            }
            else
            {
                echo 'Incorrect credentials.';
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Afterwords, you will want to perform a check for a valid `$_SESSION['userId']` value in every page where you would not like to have someone who is not logged in.

```
<?php 
    session_start();

    if(!isset($_SESSION['userId']) && $_SESSION['userId'] != 'foo')
    {
        // redirect to index.html if the form variable does not
        // contain the correct value or is not set at all.
        header('Location: index.html');
        exit(); // exit the PHP script
    }
    else
    {
        // do something or nothing here
    }
?>
```

This should be the barebones of what you need to make a login-restricted webpage. Let me know if you would like further clarification on anything mentioned.